# Run a new process in a CMD window without the title in C#?

Tags: c#, cmd, titlebar

I am trying to run a command in CMD in an external process from C#, but without the title in the CMD window. The problem is that some of the commands that are run contain usernames and passwords, that I do not want visible, in the CMS window title.

ie:

[image]

Is there a way to suppress the title from displaying when I run the process, or hide the command details?

Thanks!

-Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Prefix this to your CMD parameters

```
title &
```

ie

```
title & login commands etc
```

You could also give it a generic title like this:

```
title Login & login commands etc
```

Comment: I tried this and "Login" appeared in the title with the rest of the command. I need to hide the command being executed as it shows the login parameters.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to clear title text then the follow for your reference.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);

SetWindowText(process.MainWindowHandle, "")
```

But I am still finding a solution to hide the **title bar** and (- , X ) **widget**